# spring liquibase / hsqldb integration

Tags: hsqldb, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I am trying to load an embedded hsqldb with data using SpringLiquibase integration.

java config=

```
@Configuration
@Profile("testing")
...
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource ds =  new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
    .setName("junittest")
    .build();

    return ds;
}

@Bean
SpringLiquibase liquibase(){
    SpringLiquibase lb = new SpringLiquibase();
    lb.setDataSource(dataSource());
    lb.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase/example.xml");
    lb.setContexts("testing");

    return lb;
}
...
```

liquibase schema=example.sql
    create table xyz(
        id integer, 
        name varchar(10)
    );

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:211)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:151)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:182)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:345)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:168)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(StandardLockService.java:138)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:85)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:185)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.SchemaSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(SchemaSnapshotGenerator.java:74)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:59)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:62)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:153)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:56)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:33)
        at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:22)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:126)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:119)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:107)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.has(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:97)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.hasDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:166)
    ... 50 more
```

version of `hsqldb / liquibase : 1.8.0.10 / 3.2.3`

Am I missing some config here?

Comment: Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC

Comment: yes, but I can't seem to figure out what this means. Neither can I find and API to set this 'catalog/schemas'. I came across one `setDefaultSchema`, but this doesn't change the result.

Comment: however this works when i use a mysql as the backend. So the problems seems of hsqldb config.

Comment: There were some bugfixes in schema name handling in 3.3. Can you try it with the newest 3.3.0 instead of 3.2.3?

Comment: @Nathan Same bug.  Tried it with 3.3.0, no change.

Comment: @jordanpg What about 3.3.2?

Comment: @NathanVoxland same result.  I can do a bug report somewhere if desired.

Comment: @jordanpg Thanks for testing. Report it to liquibase.jira.com